# Why select is showing first of it's element when it's binded to model

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

I have a select in angular6 in which option is iterating over an array.
That array has one pipe which dynamically changes array value.
The problem is that when I have one selected value in model and array get changed and that value is not available in that array on which it iterates. Then select by default showing the first element but it should show empty select.
Kindly suggest me the best way to do it.

```
<select
      (change)="handleOfferChange()"
      class="alc-form-control"
      name="offer"
      id="offer"
      [(ngModel)]="detailCopy.allowedOffers">
      <option
        *ngFor="let offer of providerMaster | active: activeOnly"
        [ngValue]="[offer.csaid]"
        >{{ offer.csaid }}</option
      >
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reset the `ngModel`, to do this you have to pass `ngModel` to you pipe as an argument and in your pipe when your array changes, reset the `ngModel` to empty value (Shown below)

```
//yourTemplate.html
<select [(ngModel)]="detailCopy.allowedOffers" #mySelectModel="ngModel">
<option *ngFor="let offer of providerMaster | active: activeOnly : mySelectModel" [ngValue]="[offer.csaid]" >{{ offer.csaid }}</option>
</select>

//yourPipe.ts
......
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

transform(arr: any[], mySelectModel: NgModel): any {
 if (your logic and conditions) {
  mySelectModel.reset();
  return arr;
 }
}
```